# mysql query that repeats itself indefinitely

Tags: mysql

I need to make a query that repeats itself indefinitely meaning that I need the event to take place every time it has ended. I cannot use event every 1-2 seconds because over time the query becomes more time consuming and if I understood correctly, it would start several events at the same time with the same query?

is it even possible to accomplish in mysql or should I use a bash script for that?

Comment: I think it would be useful to understand a bit more about what you're trying to do

Comment: Ask the resource that needs the results of the query to make a call whenever it needs the data. MySQL native Events allow 1 second as the minimum interval between calls. Although, you could set up a system where a Trigger might work for you. Please share more details so that some one can attempt to answer.

Comment: i have this query that gives timediffs and other data from another table. i used create view for that until this view became ca 15 seconds long. I figured i would make another table with repeating query that keeps this info on this table up to date. i cannot have all data in one table because the source table might have 1 row and the calculated table can have several based on the duration of an event. i'm not sure this clarified anything...

Comment: It sounds like a script with an infinite loop is what you need.

Comment: yes. but how and is mysql able to do this? or should i use linux bash script?

Comment: @MontyPython The issue he's trying to solve is that he doesn't want the query to run multiple times simultaneously, because it's expensive. The event scheduler doesn't work if he runs them too often, and a trigger won't work because it will run the query as often as something else modifies the table.

Comment: @Gusmar A Linux bash script seems perfect for it.

Comment: `while :; do mysql -e 'your query'; done`

Comment: @Barmar - You're right, in that case a bash script seems fine.

Comment: triggers might work but not for this query that i already have. i know i need to reinvent how the second table is being filled in and the way to go would be a trigger